# how to incorporate wordpress wp_mail() function to a react plugin?

Tags: php, reactjs, typescript, wordpress

I need an emailing system for my react app(typescript).
Im making it as a plugin for my wordpress page, so i wanted to incorporate it with the wp_email() function.
The problem is i don't really know much about php, an although the data is sent, the response i receive is not a  valid json.

I tried this code on my react app

```
...
const sendEmail = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                '/wp-json/custom/v1/send-email',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'to': emailData.to,
                        'subject': emailData.subject,
                        'message': emailData.message
                    }),
                }
            );
             const data = await response.json();

             
            if (data.message === 'Email sent successfully.') {
                alert('Email sent successfully.');
            } else {
                alert('Email sending failed.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error sending email:', error);
        }
    };
...
```

and this code for the .php file:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_custom_email_endpoint');

function register_custom_email_endpoint() {
    register_rest_route('custom/v1', '/send-email', array(
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'send_custom_email',
    ));
}

function send_custom_email($request) {
    $to      = $request->get_param('to');
    $subject = $request->get_param('subject');
    $message = $request->get_param('message');
   // $headers = 'Content-Type: text/html';

    $result = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);

    if ($result) {
        return array('message' => 'Email sent successfully.');
    } else {
        return array('message' => 'Email sending failed.');
    }
}
```

the error im getting is
`Error sending email: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: A remark: using `custom` for your API slug is, if you want your plugin to coexist with others,  not a great choice. Please make it much more distinctive.